# MongoDB: Can't drop local database with root user

Tags: root, mongodb

I am trying to drop the `local` database in my replica set so that I can rename the replica set, but I keep getting the below error

```
errmsg" : "not authorized on local to execute command { dropDatabase: 1.0, lsid: { id: UUID(\"4a92bd75-2e25-4fab-abd7-2d72f65050c7\") }, $db: \"local\" }"
```

I am using a user who has `root` privileges and I am using MongoDB 4.0. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

These suggestions weren't working for me in Mongo 5.0.8, setting authorisation to not enabled didn't allow me to drop the local database, adding root role to my user didn't allow me to drop the database, but this was the solution

```
use admin;
db.grantRolesToUser("adminUser", ["__system"]);
use local
db.dropDatabase()
use admin;
db.revokeRolesFromUser("adminUser", ["__system"]);
```

and then running looks like this

```
local> use admin;
switched to db admin
admin> db.grantRolesToUser("adminUser", ["__system"]);
{ ok: 1 }
admin> use local
switched to db local
local> db.dropDatabase()
{ ok: 1, dropped: 'local' }
local> use admin;
switched to db admin
admin> db.revokeRolesFromUser("adminUser", ["__system"]);
{ ok: 1 }
```

Comment: OP is using MongoDB 4.0

Comment: Works with 4.4, at least.

Answer (score 1):

From [Mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/built-in-roles/#dbAdminAnyDatabase), although your user has `root` role, you can't interact with `local` and `config` databases. You'll need to create a new user with `dbAdmin` role in the `local` database. This change was implemented from Mongo 3.4

Another approach is to disable authorization from the security section in `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
security:
  authorization: disabled
```

This way an anonymous user can perform any action on any database. This one is less recommended unless you are the only one having access to the Mongo node. Just make sure to reactivate it once you're done removing `local` database.